# what is diffrence in this code with mainbundle and without?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hello i see this new code for me ,like this for push

```
tw *obj =[[tw alloc]initWithNibName:@"tw" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

normally i write code like this

```
tw *obj =[[tw alloc]initWithNibName:@"tw" bundle:nil];
```

what is difference in this bundle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no difference in this case.

passing nil to `initWithNibName:bundle:` has a special meaning. if the parameter is nil, it means the implementation should use `[NSBundle mainBundle]`.

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

The bundle in which to search for the nib file. This method looks for the nib file in the bundle's language-specific project directories first, followed by the Resources directory. If nil, this method looks for the nib file in the main bundle.

So there is no difference.

Comment: if there is no diffrence then y shoud it crash when i write [nsbundle mainbundle] code instead of nil

Comment: No, it won't crash. When you're calling that method with nil the [nsbundle mainbundle] is set implicitly